# Getbuffer method in SimpleITK libraries to read an image and output another

Tags: c#, pointers, image-processing, itk, simpleitk

Here there,

I'm currently working on a C# project and I need to create a snippet using `SimpleITK` libraries, in which my image matrix `ArrayIn` will be compared to a number `DoubleVar`.

Then, if, for each element, the value of `ArrayIn` is greater than the DoubleVar one, the respective element of my output image `ArrayOut` will be 1. If not, that element will be 0. The matrix `ArrayOut` is a binary Image , with ones and zeros. The size of AArrayOut will be the same as the input's one. I need to use the function `Getbufferasint16()` but I can't do so.

The following code is part of intents , but with no result

```
uint8_t *buffer = (my image) ->GetBufferAsUInt16();
buffer[c + numComponents*(x+ xSize* (y*+ySize*z))];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find this new example on how to access a buffer from SimpleITK in C#:
http://www.itk.org/SimpleITKDoxygen/html/ImageGetBuffer_8cs-example.html

You need to you need to use the [Marshal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class to safely interface the unmanaged code with the C# data, or use an unsafe block:

```
  input = SimpleITK.Cast(input, PixelId.sitkFloat32);
  // calculate the nubmer of pixels
  VectorUInt32 size = input.GetSize();
  int len = 1;
  for (int dim = 0; dim < input.GetDimension(); dim++) {
    len *= (int)size[dim];
  }
  IntPtr buffer = input.GetBufferAsFloat();
  // There are two ways to access the buffer:
  // (1) Access the underlying buffer as a pointer in an "unsafe" block
  // (note that in C# "unsafe" simply means that the compiler can not
  // perform full type checking), and requires the -unsafe compiler flag
  unsafe {
    float* bufferPtr = (float*)buffer.ToPointer();
    // Now the byte pointer can be accessed as per Brad's email
    // (of course this example is only a 2d single channel image):
    // This is a 1-D array but can be access as a 3-D. Given an
    // image of size [xS,yS,zS], you can access the image at
    // index [x,y,z] as you wish by image[x+y*xS+z*xS*yS],
    // so x is the fastest axis and z is the slowest.
    for (int j = 0; j < size[1]; j++) {
      for (int i = 0; i < size[0]; i++) {
        float pixel = bufferPtr[i + j*size[1]];
        // Do something with pixel here
      }
    }
  }
  // (2) Copy the buffer to a "safe" array (i.e. a fully typed array)
  // (note that this means memory is duplicated)
  float[] bufferAsArray = new float[len]; // Allocates new memory the size of input
  Marshal.Copy(buffer, bufferAsArray, 0, len);
  double total = 0.0;
  for (int j = 0; j < size[1]; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size[0]; i++) {
      float pixel = bufferAsArray[i + j*size[1]];
      total += pixel;
    }
  }
```